ngx-Editor in Angular Not working as expected
ngx-editor is not working as expected the block, italics, blockQuotes and list is not working in my angular code. either i have to remove those options from editor-menu, or i have make those working please help.
how to do this please help
<div class="comments-div" *ngIf="issueId">
                        <h4>Comments</h4>
                        <div *ngFor="let comment of comments" class="each-comment">
                            <div class="personal-info">
                                <div class="profile-pic"><img src="../../../../../assets/images/2.jpg"></div>
                                <span class="profile-name">{{comment.user}}</span>
                                <span class="comment-time">{{comment.time}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="comment-text-div">
                                <div [innerHTML]="comment.comment"></div>
                                <div class="edit-reply">
                                    <span class="edit" (click)="editComment(comment.id)" *ngIf="comment.user == current_user">Edit</span>
                                    <span class="reply">Reply</span>
                                    <span class="reply" *ngIf="comment.user == current_user" (click)="deleteComment(comment.id)">Delete</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="NgxEditor__Wrapper" style="height: 150px;">
                            <ngx-editor-menu [editor]="editor"> </ngx-editor-menu>
                            <ngx-editor [editor]="editor" [(ngModel)]="html" [disabled]="false" [placeholder]="'Type here...'"></ngx-editor>
                        </div>
                        <div class="comment-button">
                            <button class="submit-button" (click)="addComment()">submit</button>
                            <button class="cancel-button" (click)="cancel()">cancel</button>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>


create a minimal reproducible example on stackblitz
